# WordPress Custom Query with 2 Meta Queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a used vehicle site. When viewing a specific vehicle, there is a section for similar vehicles. Currently, the similar vehicles are based on the vehicles with the same body style ($vehicletype).

I would like to change it to display vehicles of the same body style with a similar price. So far I've got this code working:

```
$vehicletype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Vehicle Type', true);
$id = get_the_ID();
$baseprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Retail Price', true);
$minprice = $baseprice - 10000;
$maxprice = $baseprice + 10000;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('vehicle'),
  'post__not_in' => array($id),
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_key' => 'Vehicle Type',
  'meta_value' => $vehicletype,
  'meta_key' => 'Retail Price',
  'meta_value' => $baseprice,
);
```

This obviously displays vehicles with both the same body style and the exact same price. I would like to change this so that it display not just vehicles of the exact same price but vehicles within similar price range (between $minprice and $maxprice).

I suspect it would look something like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key'     => 'Retail Price',
    'value'   => array( $minprice, $maxprice ),
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
  ),
),
```

I have tried several different ways to get this working, but all of them cause a "This page isn’t working" error page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this is the between is not working:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array
    (
        'key'     => 'Vehicle Type',
        'value'   =>  $vehicletype, 
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array
    (
        'key'     => 'Retail Price',
        'value'   =>  $minprice,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    array
    (
        'key'     => 'Retail Price',
        'value'   =>   $maxprice,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '<=',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$vehicletype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Vehicle Type', true);
$id = get_the_ID();
$baseprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Retail Price', true);
$minprice = $baseprice - 10000;
$maxprice = $baseprice + 10000;
$query = array();
$queryPrice = array();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if( "" != $vehicletype )
    $query[] = ['key'=>'Vehicle Type','value' => $vehicletype, 'compare' => '='];

if( "" != $baseprice ){
    $queryPrice[] = ['key'=>'Retail Price','value' => $minprice, 'compare' => '>'];
    $queryPrice[] = ['key'=>'Retail Price','value' => $maxprice, 'compare' => '<'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'vehicle',
    'post__not_in' => array($id),
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR ',$query )
    'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND ',$queryPrice )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Also,  your query have

```
'meta_key' => 'Vehicle Type',
'meta_key' => 'Retail Price',
```

please make sure you provided key is what is in database